# Credentials.json equivalent for authorizing an event to the Google Calendar of a visitor on a website

Tags: authorization, google-calendar-api, credentials

I am working on a website where people can create tasks on their to-do list with a deadline date. I am trying to implement a feature where the user can click on the deadline date and be prompted to add it to their Google Calendar, of course, going through all the expected authorization protocol.

I have followed the example of: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python. By modifying it, I have been able to add calendar events to my own calendar.

To the best of my understanding, to be able to pass to Google Calendar the request, I need the information enclosed in credentials.json to authorize. If I want to put any version of my site online, obviously I can't have that kind of classified information floating around.

I have two main questions: firstly, what should I be doing in terms of safe storage of that info.
Secondly, is there something I'm missing when it comes to making a request to a different user? I know that websites I have used have let me add stuff to my Google Calendar like this, but all the explanations I have found online have been convoluted and contradictory.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "making a request to a different user"?

Comment: @ale13 I mean, that it's a visitor to the site, rather than my own account.

Answer (score 1):

### There are different ways to authenticate with Google APIs

- Creating a credentials.json file is only one of them
- You can also perform implement a client-side authentication with an API-key / client-ID incorporated into your code
- You can also use a [service-account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) whereby the service acocunt keys will also be implemented in your code
- Which authentication scenario meets your needs best highly depends on your specific case.
- To start I recommend you to read the following documentation to gain a deeper understanding of the proccess:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/CredentialTypesSupportingVariousUseCases
https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158857?hl=en
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication#installed
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2